# Light complains about a directory name being used by MSI Public Properties

Tags: wix

I'm have a third party library in my WiX installation which is causing the following error when I run Light.exe:

> error LGHT0204: ICE99: The directory name:Time is the same as one of the MSI Public Properties and can cause unforeseen side effects.

I'm not really comfortable with suppressing ICE errors, and renaming directories and making changes to the third party seams like a bad idea. Are there any other alternatives?

Edit:

**Solved**

In case someone else is having similiar problems, here's the xsl I ended up using (I got it from this blog: http://installpac.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/conflict-management-in-wix/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"> 

  <xsl:template match="@*|*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" /> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
            <xsl:text>NameOfAThirdPartyLibraryImUsing_directory_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only `Id` attribute which should not be the same as MSI public properties. This is what it complains about.

Instead of

```
<Directory Id="Time">
```

Write this

```
<Directory Id="Dir_Time" Name="Time">
```

As a result, the properly named folder will be created, and the value of `Id` attribute won't conflict with MSI public properties. You can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851193/with-wix-distribute-a-program-that-uses-sqlite-must-work-on-both-32bit-and-64b), which highlights a similar problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm using heat, so I don't name the directory manually. Guess I just have to figure out how to rename it.

Comment: heat.exe accepts XSL transformations via the `-t` switch, which can be as simple as prefixing the `Id` attribute with something